# How to convert this SQL into a LINQ QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I am having trouble turning the following sql code into LINQ. I have it mostly working but I can't figure out how to get the revision from the items table which is gotten in those subqueries. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.SerialOptCon.GROUPID, TopRevsion.RevName AS NAME, 
    dbo.SerailOptionNo.PartNo, dbo.SerialOptCon.PRICE, 
    0.00 AS DISCOUNT, 
    dbo.GroupConfig.CURRENCY,
    'OPTION' AS TYPE, dbo.SerialModelGroupOptions.MODEL, 
    dbo.SerialModelGroupOptions.SEQUENCE
FROM 
    dbo.SerialModelGroupOptions 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.SerialOptCon 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.SerailOptionNo ON dbo.SerialOptCon.OptionId = dbo.SerailOptionNo.ProductOptionId 
        ON dbo.SerialModelGroupOptions.OptionPartNo = dbo.SerailOptionNo.PartNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.GroupConfig ON dbo.SerialOptCon.GROUPID = dbo.GroupConfig.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT itm1.PartNo, itm1.Revision, itm1.RevName
     FROM dbo.Items AS itm1 
     INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT PartNo, MAX(Revision) AS Revision
          FROM dbo.Items
          GROUP BY PartNo) AS itm2 ON itm1.PartNo = itm2.PartNo 
                                   AND itm1.Revision = itm2.Revision) AS TopRevsion ON dbo.SerailOptionNo.PartNo = TopRevsion.PartNo
WHERE 
    (dbo.SerialOptCon.GROUPID = '01d2b4d2-ad63-4eab-a83f-f31ea0f6274b') 
    AND (dbo.SerialModelGroupOptions.MODEL = 'abcde')
ORDER BY 
    SEQUENCE
```

Here is the LINQ query that I have currently:

```
foreach (var item in priceGroupDetailsViewModels)
{
    (from pmo in _context.SerialModelGroupOptionss
     join po in _context.SerailOptionNos on pmo.OptionPartNo equals po.PartNo
     join pop in _context.dbo.SerialOptCon on po.SerailOptionNoId equals pop.SerailOptionNoId
     join con in _context.GroupConfig on pop.GroupId equals con.GroupId
     into p
     from pmp in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join it in _context.Items on po.PartNo equals it.PartNo
     where pmp.PriceGroupId == item.PriceGroupId && pmo.Model == item.Name
     select new OptionsDetails
                 {
                     GroupId = pop.GroupId,
                     PartNo = po.PartNo,
                     Currency = pmp.Currency,
                     Sequence = pmo.Sequence,
                     Description = it.Description3
                 });
}
```

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL. The JOINs are generated by the *ORM* based on the relations between entities. Almost every time a `join` appears in a LINQ-to-EF query it means something's wrong and the entity relations are missing

Comment: @panagiotis: Only if you never have to join disparate tables, which always happens in real systems.

Comment: If you have a complex reporting query the best option is to *not* try to emulate it in your ORM with LINQ. Create a VIEW or function and map the results. ORMs are Object to Relational Mappers, not Embedded SQL. Their job is to Map Objects to Relational data. They try to give the impression of working with object graphs instead of databases. That works only up to a point. A report doesn't deal with *objects*

Comment: @RobertHarvey there are no tables in C#. Only objects. Vietnam of Computer Science and all that

Comment: Instead of trying to bend Linq to your will, try plugging your existing sql into a [raw query or stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

Comment: @RobertHarvey [Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Ninja edit.  Yes, I am aware of that article.

Comment: Show your model, otherwise purity keepers will not stop. Probably half of joins can be removed if you have navigation properties.